# How to get two maximum values in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

It only sorting the values of the data frame instead of giving the two highest values in data frame

```
 fr <- data.frame(ty,tu,ti,to,tp)
 sort(fr,decreasing = TRUE)
```

Comment: The code does exactly what you've requested it to do. Please give us an example of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unlist` before the `sort` as 'fr' is a `data.frame` and `data.frame` is a `list` having `list` elements of equal length i.e. columns.

```
head(sort(unlist(fr), decreasing = TRUE), 2)
```

#### data

```
fr <- data.frame(ty = 1:10, tu = 11:20, ti = 21:30)
```